# Auto Age Calculation On Appended Area

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am working on one registration form. in that there is a one **main form** and another are child forms.child form are not required.its an optional.it will opens on click `add more`.
Following image illustrate the process of adding child form
[image]

On click addData following form would be opens
[image]

in that i am using  `age field`. which is auto calculated on selecting date.and following is my code for **main form** to cal

```
$(document).on('change', '.dateholder1', function(e){
    var dob = new Date($(this).val());
    //var dob = e.date;
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    $(".ageclass1").val(age);
});
```

its work fine in **main form**. but how can i display age on child form?

> Please Check My Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5h1rpjqs/

Comment: please share your code for main and child form. Are those two different html pages?

Comment: I have post demo fiddle. and both are same form but child form opens only when user have to add family member as shown in image\

Comment: Something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/5h1rpjqs/5/

Comment: can you please share "ageclass1" field?

Comment: I have fully explained in fiddle

Comment: @ TarangP, Ok, Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(".ageclass1").val(age);
```

'cause we have many ".ageclass1" and browser doesn't understand which one to change and then change them all (^_^;). So we have to change that line with something like this:

```
$(this).next().val(age);
```

This is the new code

```
$(document).on('change', '.dateholder1', function(e){
    var dob = new Date($(this).val());
    //var dob = e.date;
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    $(this).next().val(age);
});

$(".addDate").click(function(){
    $("#appenddiv").append($("#appendContent").html() + "<div class='clearfix'></div>");
});
```

And this is new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5h1rpjqs/5/

```js
$(document).on('change', '.dateholder1', function(e){
    var dob = new Date($(this).val());
    //var dob = e.date;
 var today = new Date();
 var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 $(this).next().val(age);
});

$(".addDate").click(function(){
 $("#appenddiv").append($("#appendContent").html() + "<div class='clearfix'></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>This is working demo</h3><br>
<input type="text" name="date" class="dateholder1" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
<input type="text" name="age" class="ageclass1" placeholder="age">
<span class='addDate'>Add</span>
<br><br>
<div id="appenddiv">

</div>

<div style="display:none" id='appendContent'>
  <input type="text" name="date" class="dateholder1" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
  <input type="text" name="age" class="ageclass1" placeholder="age"><br>
  <span>How Can i Calculate age here On Change dateHolder</span>
</div>
```